# Usage examples show input to a python function that isn't separated by commas?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to get a bit of code that I found online to work with the usage examples given in the README.md file. The intention of the tools are to synthesize an audio scene out of separate events.I cannot figure out how to run the usage examples given, which are:

```
  * ./simscene.py -h
  Displays command line syntax and option descriptions.

  * ./simscene.py example/sound/ output/ 10 -e example/forest_events.xls -b example/forest_backgrounds.xls -N 10 -v
  Creates wavefiles and plots of 10 instances of scenes for which events are described in example/forest_events.xls and
  background sounds in example/forest_backgrounds.xls
```

I've tried running these lines on the terminal (I am using PyCharm) but the error is that "simscene.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file", even if I try to run "simscene.py" alone with no inputs.

I've been able to get the function simscene to run from another script by importing it, but then run into errors. It looks like the file simscene.py uses lines of `argparse` to prompt the user, but I can't seem to activate these prompts to start running.

How do the usage examples relay the specified inputs to the function, and how might I be able to run the usage examples?

The link to the entire project is here:
https://bitbucket.org/mlagrange/simscene/src/master/python/

Comment: Run python files with `python` or `python3`. It's not an executable.

Comment: That way of running the script is for Unix, not Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably asking you to run the file with the python interpreter, i.e. if you are in the directory,

```
python simscene.py -h
```

should probably run the first example. I assume they didn't include the `python` part, because people could have different variants (`python3`, `numba`, etc)